# Remove red underline

Tags: html, css, href

I'm trying to make some links to other pages of my websites using only href of the text, having the text a background color and hover effects defined. Everything works perfectly, except when I mouse over a red line appears in the bottom of all my words links. Even if I have different links for different words, I always get the red underline all my words. I tried already doing text-decoration:none and also the !important tag, but none of that worked. It seems like the kind of thing you would get with incorrect spelling at work.

Here's my code:

```
.text-link-style {
background-color: #40bdb3;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
font-weight: 700;
padding: 10px;
line-height: 42px;}

.text-link-style:hover {
color: white;
background: rgba(64, 189, 179, 0.8);
text-decoration: none; !important;}
```

How can I remove it?
Thanks!

Comment: show your html and css code

Comment: pls show an example (link, html, css, fiddle)!